# Injecting Repository into ActionFilter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, action-filter

I am trying to inject a repository into an action filter, but getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   '...ISqlRepository' while attempting to activate
>   '...MyActionFilterAttribute'.

I'm trying to follow Steve Smith's pattern from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/mvc/controllers/filters/sample/src/FiltersSample/Filters/LoggingAddHeaderFilter.cs).  Everything works fine until I add the ISqlRepository reference to the constructor.

Here are the relevant code bits:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<MyActionFilterAttribute>();
```

MyActionFilterAttribute.cs (I realize that I'm implementing IResultFilter here.  I'm just trying to stick as close to the example).

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute: IResultFilter
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        private ISqlRepository _sql;
        public MyActionFilterAttribute(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ISqlRepository sql)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoaderActionFilterAttribute>();
            _sql = sql;
        }
```

MyController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(MyActionFilterAttribute))]
    public class MyController: Controller
```

Comment: Did you register your repository class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ISqlRepository` to your services:

```
services.AddScoped<ISqlRepository,SqlRepository>();
```

The reason the sample project referenced did not have to do this is because `ILoggerFactory` is added via the framework.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I went with @mxmissile's solution and it seems to work!

Comment: How does that get an instance of your repo in the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to register your repository as you usually would with ioC:

```
services.AddScoped<ISqlRepository,SqlRepository>();
```

Then you'll need to do `property injection` to the attribute.

Looks like this -

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute: IResultFilter
{
    public static Func<ISqlRepository> GetSqlRepo;

    private ISqlRepository _sql;

    public MyActionFilterAttribute()
    {
        _sql = GetSqlRepo();
    }
}
```

In your startup, you'll have access to your service collection, so can do the following

```
MyActionFilterAttribute.GetSqlRepo = () => services.GetService<ISqlRepository>()
```